# what is the value that has to be supplied to Mapper coordinate in react native maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

```
const [marker, setMarker] = useState([
    {
      latLng: { latitude: 16.960775, longitude: 82.2258361 },
      title: "Best Place",
      description: "This is the best place in Portland"
    }
  ]);
```

and i was using in Mapper as below

```
 <Marker
          coordinate={marker.latLng}
          title={marker.title}
          description={marker.description}
        />
```

and it was showing error like latLng cannot be null -a position is required

Comment: your error is simple, you try to access a property of a direct marker state object, but your marker is an array with object, try `marker[0].latLng`

Answer (score 0):

```
const INITIAL_REGION = {
      latitude: 52.5,
      longitude: 19.2,
      latitudeDelta: 8.5,
      longitudeDelta: 8.5
    };

render(){
    return (
    <MapView
      initialRegion={INITIAL_REGION}
      style={{ flex: 1, zIndex: -1, ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
    >
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.0, longitude: 18.2 }} />
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.4, longitude: 18.7 }} />
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.1, longitude: 18.4 }} />
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.6, longitude: 18.3 }} />
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 51.6, longitude: 18.0 }} />
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 53.1, longitude: 18.8 }} />
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.9, longitude: 19.4 }} />
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 52.2, longitude: 21 }}   />
    </MapView>
  );
}
```

Here is a working example. Marker coordinate should be receiving **an object** which requires **latitude**, and **longitude** fields. I could not tell what is wrong with your code because of the lack of code segment example. If you want to share the whole render code segment with me, I can help you with what is wrong.

Hope that this helped you a bit. 
Have fun

Comment: by using the coordinate as in the given format worked for me but i need to give the marker object as i mentioned in the question can you tell me how to use it in that format

Comment: I think your useState part is wrong, Can you try with this:

```const [marker, setMarker] = useState({
    latLng: { latitude: 52.0, longitude: 18.2 },
    title: "Best Place",
    description: "This is the best place in Portland"
  });```


This code segment works for me.